PHP constructor property promotion: how to call the parent constructor?
So I have a Controller that I am trying to rewrite to use PHP constructor property promotion:
class MyUserController extends UserController {

  /**
   * Constructs MyUserController.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter
   *   Parent dependency.
   * @param \Drupal\user\UserStorageInterface $user_storage
   *   Parent dependency.
   * @param \Drupal\user\UserDataInterface $user_data
   *   Parent dependency.
   * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   *   Parent dependency.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Flood\FloodInterface $flood
   *   Parent dependency.
   * @param \Drupal\Component\Datetime\TimeInterface $time
   *   The time service.
   */
  public function __construct(DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter,
                              UserStorageInterface $user_storage,
                              UserDataInterface $user_data,
                              LoggerInterface $logger,
                              FloodInterface $flood,
                              TimeInterface $time) {
    parent::__construct($date_formatter, $user_storage, $user_data, $logger, $flood);
    $this->time = $time;
  }

So I did this:
  public function __construct(
    protected TimeInterface $time,
  ) {}

Wow, so much shorter!
I eliminated the parent variables like protected UserStorageInterface $userStorage because PHPStorm gives a warning:

Type must not be defined (as in base class
'\Drupal\user\Controller\UserController')

But without the parent class variables, how do I call the parent constructor?

You can't "eliminate" the arguments for the parent, they need to remain in the constructor. It's only the argument that is for your class specifically that you can use property promotion on.
For example:
class MyUserController extends UserController {

  public function __construct(
    DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter,
    UserStorageInterface $user_storage,
    UserDataInterface $user_data,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    FloodInterface $flood,
    protected TimeInterface $time,
  ) {
    parent::__construct($date_formatter, $user_storage, $user_data, $logger, $flood);
  }

}

In the current version of PHPStorm (2024.1.1), this produces no warnings.

You can't do that. But I also see more and more places where there's no constructor at all, just create(), for example in the Webform module. This allows parent classes to change their constructor without breaking any code.
See Issue #3067546 [Webform 6.x] Fix subclassing and stop overriding constructors for more references.
See this commit for the diff where the __construct() method gets removed and the create() method adjusted.
Webform's help controller:
class WebformHelpController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

  /**
   * The webform help manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\webform\WebformHelpManagerInterface
   */
  protected $help;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $instance = parent::create($container);
    $instance->help = $container->get('webform.help_manager');
    return $instance;
  }

.. and no __construct() anymore. Much shorter.

The idea of DI via __construct() is to be able to construct the class with your arguments. If you choose this approach, you must add setter methods for the same purpose. You can postpone this until you write a test needing it. But then there is nothing wrong with keeping custom code just making small changes to existing classes even simpler by accessing the container via \Drupal, you will know when it's time to use proper DI with constructors or setters.
